# iTunes Connect - Error importing this build

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store-connect

I've been trying, unsuccessfully, to upload an app to iTunes Connect for the last two weeks. Every time processing is complete I get the non helpful error "There was an error importing this build". There's no other detail with it, which really doesn't help.

It's an update to an existing app, which last time (four weeks ago) uploaded without any problems. I've made a few changes to the code since it was last uploaded, but only minor ones. The only big change was adding the Firebase SDK and removing associated domains.

I've tried the following:

- Recreating provisional profiles.
- Turning bitcode on and off.
- Removing and adding capabilities.
- Uploading from a different Mac.
- Using Xcode and application loader.
- Removing Firebase.

Apple support have not had any useful ideas yet, I was wondering if anyone here had any suggestions that I've not thought of?

Comment: what did the support guys said ?

Comment: They said to check the beta entitlement existed, which it did.

Comment: did you check the activity tab when build is uploaded, it should list the entitlements if the build has one

Comment: Yep I checked that and it was fine. Once the error shows you can no longer look at that view though, they hyperlink is disabled.

Comment: can you revert back to build ( excluding firebase )? and try to upload to see if error is resolved? If so then we need to debug for firebase releated issue. We have seen simlar errors in past but resolving entitlement cleared issue

Comment: Reverting back of a previous version still didn't work. I went back to one that uploaded successfully and this time had the same error. Right now we're recreating all of the certificates to see if that makes a difference